# mysql finding dates more than 1 week from today

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query a RADIUS database held in MySQL to determine which users have not been logged in for over a week.

Each record has a username, the last time they registered to RADIUS (starttime) and the last time they un-registered (stoptime).

starttime and stoptime are time/date formats like '2018-01-16 12:01:00'.

I know I have 1 user who has been "down" since May of last year, so I'm using him to test.

My first test:

```
select 
    username,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( hour, max(stoptime), NOW() )  as diff
from
    radacct
where
    username='waljo'
```

produces the correct result of
waljo,6824

Now, if I try the same query by adding diff > 168 (the number of hours in a week)

```
select 
    username,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( hour, max(stoptime), NOW() )  as diff
from
    radacct
having diff > 168
and
    username='waljo'
```

I get zero results. WHY?

Ultimately, I want to do something like this, showing anyone who has disconnected and not started for over 1 week.

```
select 
    username,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( hour, max(stoptime), NOW() )  as diff
from
    radacct
having max(stoptime) > max(starttime)  
and
diff > 168
```

This too returns zero results.

Comment: Something like `select username from radacct group by username having max(stoptime) < now() - interval 7 day`

Comment: `HAVING` is for post-aggregation group filtering, you have not created any

Comment: check this before using [SQL Having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thank you.

This seems to give the results I wanted:

```
select 
    username,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( day, max(stoptime), NOW() )  as diff,
    max(stoptime) as maxstop,
    max(starttime) as maxstart
from
    radacct
group by username
having diff > 7
and
maxstop > maxstart
order by diff desc
```